# Programatically open a dialog as popup with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

So I have a page and a dialog. When the user click the page button, one AJAX request will open the dialog with the results. Something like that simple example without AJAX: http://jsfiddle.net/rBBpx/

It works. The dialog opens programatically. But it hides the page content, showing the dialog as if it's another page. I know that popup's can open dialogs in-page with links, but I didn't get the point in how I can do that programatically.
I tried to change `$.mobile.changePage()` call to that, but it didn't worked as I expected:

```
$('#dialog').popup();
$('#dialog').popup('open');
```

How can I show that dialog in-page, as a popup? Is it ever possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dialog is different than a popup. This is a popup http://jsfiddle.net/rBBpx/1/

Comment: @Paulo Freitas did you read the latest jqm docs? They seem to explain it fairly well. The trickiest part should only be I'm deciphering if you want a dialogue or a popup. As Omar pointed out, they are different things.

Answer (score -2):

In case you use phonegap, there is an alert plugin: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

```
navigator.notification.alert("your AJAX result here");
```